# Derivations in Finite algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

I frequently work with algebras over finite fields that are defined via structure constants. In particular, these algebras are not required to possess any particular or additional properties; they are always non-unital, non-commutative and non-associative. I'm curious if it's still possible to define derivations or some suitable generalizations of them in these type of algebras. Any references/comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does SWA mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWA doesn't seem to help.